# Font size in animation using Python

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

How do I increase the font size of the numbers in the heatmap as well as the colorbar? The numbers are too small as can be seen below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from celluloid import Camera

a = np.array([[0.31131114, 0.96641729, 0.72632796],
       [0.42412489, 0.66088661, 0.60893906],
       [0.64454019, 0.509509  , 0.66285615]])

b = np.array([0.31131114, 0.42412489, 0.509509  , 0.64454019])

fig, (ax1, cbar_ax) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [20, 2]},
                                   figsize=(25,25))
camera = Camera(fig)
sns.set_style('white')
rectangles = []
for bb in b.flatten():
    sns.heatmap(a, linewidth=2, ax=ax1, annot=True, cbar_ax=cbar_ax)
    rectangles.append(plt.Rectangle((np.where(a == bb)[1][0], np.where(a == bb)[0][0]), 1,1,
                                    fc='green', ec='green', lw=5, clip_on=False))
    for rect in rectangles:
        ax1.add_patch(rect)
    camera.snap()

animation = camera.animate(interval=800)
animation.save('Today_3x3.gif')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `sns.set(font_scale=3)`

Comment: `cbar_ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)` to just change the fontsize of the colorbar tick labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Adjust your figure size so that it's smaller (so your text, relatively, is bigger)

or

- Scale up the SNS font sizes using `sns.set(font_scale=3)` (credit [@JohanC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71035936/font-size-in-animation-using-python/71036023#comment125575050_71035936))

Comment: Good point, adjusted and credited you :)

Comment: @JohanC it works just put it before `plt.subplots` definition